# More effects, to one function. Jquery

Tags: jquery, function, fadein, effect

I have a function, that will print out some text, while an iframe content is loading:

```
 // set "waiting" message:
   $("#loadingStatus").html("Waiting for your advertisements to load...");
```

My question is, how do I add the fadeIn("slow") to the loading message above? 
I tried adding .fadeIn("slow") in the same line, but that did not work.

Comment: Was your #loadingStatus initially hidden?

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to hide your element first, since [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) won't do anything if the element is already visible:

```
$("#loadingStatus").hide().html("Waiting for your advertisements to load...")
                   .fadeIn("slow");
```

Comment: That did the trick! What if I want to use the fadeIn() function on an iframe?

Comment: You should have no problem calling `fadeIn()` on an `<iframe>` element (if that's what you're asking).

Comment: The same logic applies: is your `<iframe>` element hidden when you call `fadeIn()`?

Comment: No it's not. But I am not sure on how to use the hide() function when it comes to iFrames. Since I tried hiding it, but the effect wasn't there.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is, make the `#loadingStatus` fadeOut/hide first and then add the html and then fadeIn again like so:

```
$('#loadingStatus').hide().html('Your message here').fadeIn('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide it first:

```
$("#loadingStatus").hide().html("Waiting for your advertisements to load...").fadeIn("slow");
```